# Express Checkout Paypal in project GWT, only the first time doPayment doesn't works

Tags: gwt, express-checkout, paypal

I'm using Express Checkout PayPal in my GWT-RPC Project. When for the first time after the running of SuperDev Mode on Eclipse I use [SDK merchant](http://paypal.github.io/sdk/#merchant) method doExpressCheckoutPayment (on server side) I receive ack=FAILURE with the error 10001, I've seen that it's identified as an internal error, you can look it [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/#id09C3F05600A)
I'm using a lot this method, because I'm testing my code. I' ve noticed that my sandbox account payer has finished virtual money on paypal. So maybe it could be that the problem? My code for payment is the following:

```
public DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseType doPaymentExpressCheckout(String token, String payerID){
    try {
        GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseType getExpressCheckoutDetails=getExpressCheckoutDetails(token);
        PaymentDetailsType paymentDetail = new PaymentDetailsType();
        BasicAmountType orderTotal = new BasicAmountType();
        orderTotal.setValue(getExpressCheckoutDetails.getGetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails().getPaymentDetails().get(0).getOrderTotal().getValue());
        orderTotal.setCurrencyID(CurrencyCodeType.fromValue("EUR"));
        paymentDetail.setOrderTotal(orderTotal);
        paymentDetail.setPaymentAction(PaymentActionCodeType.fromValue("Sale"));
        List<PaymentDetailsType> paymentDetails = new ArrayList<PaymentDetailsType>();
        paymentDetails.add(paymentDetail);

        DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetailsType doExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetails = new DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetailsType();
        doExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetails.setToken(token);
        doExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetails.setPayerID(payerID);
        doExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetails.setPaymentDetails(paymentDetails);

        DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestType doExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest = new DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestType(doExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetails);
        doExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest.setVersion("104.0");

        DoExpressCheckoutPaymentReq doExpressCheckoutPaymentReq = new DoExpressCheckoutPaymentReq();
        doExpressCheckoutPaymentReq.setDoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest(doExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest);

        Map<String, String> confiMap=Configuration.getAcctAndConfig();
        PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(confiMap);
        DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseType doExpressCheckoutPaymentResponse = service.doExpressCheckoutPayment(doExpressCheckoutPaymentReq); 

        return doExpressCheckoutPaymentResponse;
    } catch (SSLConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidCredentialException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HttpErrorException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidResponseDataException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientActionRequiredException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MissingCredentialException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OAuthException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Besides on Eclipse console appears this snippet:

```
GET /recompile/MovieUniverse
   Job it.myproject.movieuniverse.MovieUniverse_1_11
      starting job: it.myproject.movieuniverse.MovieUniverse_1_11
      binding: user.agent=safari
      skipped compile because no input files have changed
      0.036s total -- Compile completed
```

I think that SDK merchant uses soap because appear output like this:

```
INFO: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes" xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes"><soapenv:Header><ns:RequesterCredentials><ebl:Credentials...
```

thanks a lot for your attention!

Comment: I think that the problem was the paypal balance for test accounts equal to zero. I 've fill it and the error doesn't appear anymore

Comment: 10001 internal error can mean a lot of different things.  If it happens continuously then you could have a problem with your request.  If it's sporadic then it's probably just PayPal's server timing out.

Comment: Got it, anyway the problem was the PayPal balance equal to zero